Approximation of blocking probability
I want to compute the blocking probability \begin{align*}
\operatorname{B}\left(\rho,m\right) & = \dfrac{\rho^{m}/m!}
{\sum_{i= 0}^{m}\rho^{i}/i!}
\\[5mm] \mbox{with}\ \left(\rho,m\right)
 & = \left(ka, k\left[a - 1\right]\right)
\end{align*}
( Erlang $\operatorname{B}$ formula ) for 'billionaire' $k \gg a$.

My naïve approach is by Stirling approximation:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\rho^{m}}{m!} & \approx\frac{\rho^{m}}{\,\sqrt{\,2\pi m\,}\,\left(m/{\rm e}\right)^{m}}, \quad\sum_{i= 0}^{m}\frac{\rho^{i}}{i!}\approx e^{\rho}
\\[2mm] & \mbox{when}\ m\ \mbox{large and}\
\rho\ \mbox{also large}
\end{align*}
but this seems not good enough.
I need your help to get a better approximation.
However, I googled many times about
'Approximation of blocking probability' but cannot find such an alternative approximated
formula, I feel interested in understanding why.

Thanks a real lot !.
Edit: I find a better approximation for the numerator here. And I hope for an approximation of factorial sum
$$
\sum_{iv= 0}^{m}\frac{\rho^{i}}{i!}\quad
\mbox{as}\quad
c\,{\rm e}^{\rho + o\left(1\right)}
$$
sharpening the traditional exponential function ${\rm e}^{\rho}$
Edit $\bf 2$: I think Taylor's series with remainder helps here.

What happens if you substitute $\rho = ka$ and $m = k(a-1)$ in the approximations at the bottom? Incidentally, I assume the last two $p$'s are actually $\rho$'s?

@BrianTung yes, your sense is right, seems like nothing special about $\left ( \rho, m \right )= \left ( ka, k\left ( a- 1 \right ) \right )$, maybe $\operatorname{gcd}\left ( \rho, m \right )= k$ makes the problem more general. I also fixed the wrong $\rho$. Thank you so much, sir.

Some context? Where does this "blocking probability" comes from?

@leonbloy its another name is Erlang B formula, and it is also the special case of Erlang distribution. Thanks for your help.

In case this helps: https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11 see 8.11.7

@leonboy it's hard to me, but I will try. Thank you so much.

To first order $$B\approx \frac{1}{a} \tag1$$
Proof follows (I moved to the end my original proof, much more convoluted and less reliable).

Consider $$ \frac{1}{B}=\frac{m!}{\rho ^m} \sum_{i= 0}^{m}\frac{\rho^i}{i!}= \sum_{j= 0}^{m} \rho^{-j} \frac{m!}{(m-j)!} \tag 2$$
Now, assuming  $m=k(a-1)$ , $\rho = ka$, with $a>1$, $k\gg a$:
$$\begin{align}\rho^{-j} \frac{m!}{(m-j)!}&= \left(\frac{m}{\rho} \right)^j \left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{m}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{j-1}{m}\right)
\\ &= \left(\frac{a-1}{a}\right)^j \left(1 - \frac{1+2 +\cdots +(j-1)}{m}+o(m^{-1})\right) \\
 &= \alpha^j \left(1 - \frac{j (j-1)}{2m}+o(m^{-1})\right) \tag3 \\
\end{align}$$
where $\alpha = (a-1)/a$.  Replacing the finite sum in $(2)$ by an infinite sum, and using $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \alpha^j j(j-1)=2 \alpha^2/(1-\alpha)^3$ this results in
$$ 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{B}\approx \frac{1}{1-\alpha} - \frac{1}{m}\frac{\alpha^2}{(1-\alpha)^3}=a - \frac{1}{k(a-1)}\frac{a^3 (a-1)^2}{a^2}=a - \frac{1}{k} a(a-1)  \tag4
\end{align}
$$
or
$$ B \approx \frac{1}{a - \frac{1}{k} a(a-1) } \tag 5$$
For example, for $k=50$ and $a=3.5$ ($m=125$) we get:
             B          rel error  
exact      0.298436
aprox (1)  0.285714      4.2%
aprox (5)  0.300752     -0.8%


Alternative original derivation (less reliable).
$$\begin{align}
g(m,x)=\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \frac{x^j}{j!} = e^x \frac{\Gamma(m,x)}{\Gamma(m)}\end{align}
$$
Setting $m=k(a-1)$, $x=ka$, with $a>1$ fixed and $k\to \infty$, applying asympotic formula $8.11.7$ from here for the incomplete Gamma function, and Stirling approximation for the Gamma function , we get
$$\log g(m,x) \approx -\frac12\left(\alpha \,k + \log k  + \beta\right)$$
with $\alpha = 2 (a-1)\left(\log(\frac{a-1}{a}) -1 \right)$ and $\beta = \log \frac{2\pi}{a-1}$
Then, doing the math...
$$ \log \frac{g(m,x)}{\frac{x^m}{m!}} \approx \log(a-1) + \frac{1}{12 (ak)^2} + o(1/k^2)
 $$
and finally
$$ B = \frac{1}{1+\frac{g(m,x)}{\frac{x^m}{m!}}}\approx \frac{1}{a} $$

@leonboy thank you for investing your time in my problem; your solution has made the most effective use of intentional $\left ( \rho, m \right )$.

I see your simpler derivation, sir.

I had made a little mistake. Fixed, I hope

Very complete and detailed, sir.
